# on scroll once element is in view - detach event from element but not from rest

Tags: jquery

I get "e is not defined" error, and if I set the e on the scroll it works for the first element but then it's detached for the rest. What I'm trying to do is - once the element is in view the first time, to detach the event to stop it from firing on each scroll movement.

```js
($.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var a = $(this).offset().top,
      c = a + $(this).outerHeight(),
      b = $(window).scrollTop(),
      d = b + $(window).height();
    return c > b && a < d;
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.title1').isInViewport(e)) {
      console.log('title1');
      $(this).off(e);
    } else if ($('.title2').isInViewport(e)) {
      console.log('title2');
      $(this).off(e);
    } else if ($('.title2').isInViewport(e)) {
      console.log('title2');
      $(this).off(e);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="title1">Title1</h2>
<div style="height: 600px;"></div>
<h2 class="title2">Title2</h2>
<div style="height: 600px;"></div>
<h2 class="title3">Title3</h2>
```

---

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]

Comment: But you are not assigning an event handler. You are just testing the position of the element on the window scroll event. So you just have to STOP showing it

Comment: I'm trying to stop the isInViewport from firing once it triggers the first time. How would I remove it after the first time? The window scroll is trigger it each time and it's not ideal for performance or anything for that matter.

Comment: You are console.logging something in the window.scroll event. Just stop console.logging it

Comment: By using ```$(this).off(e)``` you are unbinding the ```$(window).scroll()``` from the window. Since $(this) refers to the element the function has been called on (scope). It won't make sense to unbind the 'title1' element either. My first guess would be to set a flag variable (Boolean). Then you can check if the flag has been set to true already and return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning an event handler. You are just testing the position of the element on the window scroll event. So you just have to STOP showing it

```js
($.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var a = $(this).offset().top,
    c = a + $(this).outerHeight(),
    b = $(window).scrollTop(),
    d = b + $(window).height();
  return c > b && a < d;
});

const classesToMonitor = [".title1","title2","title3"];
const len = classesToMonitor.length;
classesToMonitor.forEach(cls => $(cls).data("monitor",true));
let stopped = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (stopped === len) return;  // don't even test
  $('.title1, title2, .title3').each(function() { // we could even splice the array
    if ($this().isInViewport() && $(this).data("monitor")) {
      console.log($(this).attr("class"))
      $(this).data("monitor",false);
      stopped++;
    }
  })
});
```